# Bootstrap Navbar dropdown list become messy in desktop but not in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing a problem because i don't study more about `design part`
I am using a Template from `w3layouts.com` under `Education` section using `Tutoring` Template. It is bootstrap based template.

Demo Page Edited by me is here [Demo Page](http://practicalfile.com/theam/)

I am using `dropdown` button facility of bootstrap.
When I open check dropdown button `Downloads` in my laptop it looks like this
[image]

When I am opening this same page on my mobile(actually I reduced web browser size) it looks like this
[image]

As you can see in above image with `Desktop View` it looks messy...
What should I do now code is given below.

```
<div class="header" id="home">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html" class="hvr-bounce-to-top">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

                  <!-- Problem Start From Here -->
                  <!-- Problem Start From Here -->
                  <!-- Problem Start From Here -->

                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Downloads <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">                      
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Practical Files</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Selected Download</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List View Mode</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Cover/Index Pages</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Front/Cover Pages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Index Pages</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Reports Format</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Major/Minor Format</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Industrial File Format</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Reports Files</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Major/Minor Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Industrial Training</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <!-- Till Here -->
                <!-- Till Here -->
                <!-- Till Here Maybe -->

                <li><a href="about.html" class="hvr-bounce-to-top">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html" class="hvr-bounce-to-top">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" class="hvr-bounce-to-top">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

If there is any requirement for any other codes or full code please let me know.
I tried to add and remove codes in html but always makes it more messy...

Comment: have you consider using css to properly style your menus?

Comment: I made no change in the template css and rest of the code scripts you can 
see the template additional css script here [link](https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/tutoring/web/)

Comment: i don't see any submeniu in the demo you provide that means you need to style it yourself

Comment: Sorry for last link please check out new updated link for here [link](http://practicalfile.com/theam/) Thank You for giving me your valuable time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
.navbar-nav li {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

to

```
.navbar-nav> li {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I am going to try this now.

Comment: Thanks It works fine... just like I want

you can see updates here[link](http://practicalfile.com/theam/)

Comment: Sorry to disturb you. but can you please tell me the difference between both (if you don't have any problem)

Comment: if i understand correctly. .navbar li means a li directly after the class navbar .navbar > li any sub element that is li

Comment: ok means last time it was not including the `dropdown` li but after using `>` It includes all the li.

Comment: `.navbar > li` direct child elements ` .navbar  li` all child li elements

Comment: means .navbar-nav> li is applied only to direct child, and don't affect the `dropdown` menu li child (Sorry I am weak in english)